# WPF Item binding

Tags: wpf

i am trying to bind to rectangle with each other. so when ever a rectangle move the second one move, i am still new to WPF!!! and i know this might sounds really stupid all help are really welcome. please find below my code and help me pls

```
       <Canvas Height="500" Width="500" Name="Window1canvas"
            Background="BLUE"
            DnD:DragDropManager.DragSource="{StaticResource sourceForDragOp}"
            DnD:DragDropManager.DropTarget="{StaticResource targetForDragOp}">

        <Rectangle Name="Rec1" Width="50"
               Height="50"
               Fill="Yellow" 
               Canvas.Left="251"
               Canvas.Top="288"/>


        <Rectangle Width="50"
               Height="50"
               Fill="Green"
               Canvas.Left="{Binding ElementName=Rec1, Path=(Canvas.Left), Mode=TwoWay}"
               Canvas.Top="100"/>



        </Canvas>
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code? .. you already bound the left of the second rectangle with the first one .. what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define rectangles position in view model and bind it to rectangles using TwoWay binding.